# How to improve this association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hey guys
I want to build a database and some association between them, below are some descriptions

1. Drummer and Video are many-to-many association, because, sometimes, more than one drummer will appear on one video clip
2. Cymbal and Video are only many-to-many association, same reason
3. Event and Video are one-to-many, because it makes sense that one video only represent only one Event

so for the first two my solution is using two has-and-belongs-to-many association sign to the both side,  and for the 3rd one i use simple one-to-many:
here's the code:

```
class Drummer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :videos
end

class Cymbal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :videos
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :drummers
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cymbals
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos
end
```

But I think the polymorphic is the better solutions, video should apply two many other models, but I don't know how to make a many-to-many polymorphic association, i already ask a question about this

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
class Interpreter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :video
end

class Drummer < Interpreter
end

class Cymbal < Interpreter
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :interpreters
  has_and_belongs_to_many :drummers
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cymbals
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos
end
```

`Video.first.interpreters` should return all drumers and cymbals, while `Video.first.drummers` and `Video.first.cymbals` will return only corresponding models
`Cymbals` and `Drummers` will share same database table `interpreters`

Answer (score 0):

Have you watched this http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association